# How can I get the current NodeRef when clicking on an Alfresco custom action icon?

Tags: alfresco

I have created a custom Alfresco action. The action is triggered when the user clicks 
the action icon on the alfresco item. This brings up a jsp page.
What I want to do is display the name of the item on which the action is being done.

Comment: are you using alfresco explorer or share?

Comment: Are you using a JSP Dialog?